# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'validate'? IN FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

> NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'validate'

Exception caught by gesture.
Why my validate method is not working in below code:

login.dart

```
                       Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed:(){
                                  if(_formKey.currentState.validate())// validate method
                                {
                                    print('validated');
                                  }
                                },
                                child:Text('LogIn',style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),),),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: Are you assigning the `_formKey` to a form?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a `GlobalKey<FormState>`,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

after creating the global key
then use the key in the form

```
Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Add TextFormFields and ElevatedButton here.
    TextFormField(
      // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
    ),
    
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
          // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
          );
        }
      },
      child: const Text('Submit'),
    ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```